# jQuery file upload with the same name does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

We created a one pager website with c#, js, jquery. I have a normal upload form wich calles the c# controller for the upload. Is the upload finish the same window is refreshed and shows the up the new file in the list of all files.

It can be that the user sees that he has an error in the file and reuploads the file. If the page is not reladed the file can not be uploaded. my triger function is not working anymore.

how can I upload a file twice with the exact same name without refreshing the page manually?

my upload trigger function

```js
// formUploadRisk-Formular open
    $("#uploadRiskPolicyFile").change(function () {
        if (confirm("Would you like to upload the file?")) {
            var riskId = $(managementRiskPdfMenu).data("riskId");
            var control = document.getElementById("uploadRiskPolicyFile");
            var files = control.files[0];
            var success = UploadRiskPdf(riskId, 1, files);
            if (success) {
                LoadManagementPdfMenu(riskId);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

my uploadfunction

```js
function UploadRiskPdf(riskId, documentTypeID, files) {

    var result = false;

    // Methode to save
    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('file', files);

    var uploadURL = "documents/upload/risk/" + riskId + "/" + documentTypeID;

    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            return $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        },
        url: uploadURL,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fd,
        success: function (response) {
            var node
            result = true;
            var d = data;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Some error!")
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

and my html will appendet like this

```js
var documentRow = $.parseHTML('<div><span><a class="risikoPdf" href="documents/customer/' + value.DocumentID + '" target="_blank"><i style="margin-right:5px;" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x"></i>' + value.UploadDate + '_' + value.ProgramCode + '</a></span><span class="document-edit-delete fa fa-trash fa-2x"></span></div>');


$("#" + layoutId).append(documentRow);
```

and my html

```html
<div id="uploadPdfDocumentPolicy" class="uploaderRisiko">
                <div class="browser">
                    <label>
                        <span>Policen</span>
                        <input id="uploadRiskPolicyFile" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" type="file" name="FileUploadPolicy" title="Klicken, um eine weitere Rechnung hochzuladen" />
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="uploadPdfDocumentBill" class="uploaderRisiko">
                <div class="browser">
                    <label>
                        <span>Rechnungen</span>
                        <input id="uploadRiskBillFile" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" type="file" name="FileUploadBill" title="Klicken, um eine weitere Rechnung hochzuladen" />
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I made a checker variable who checks if the value isn't empty. After the succsess I clear the value of the input field. Because, this is a change to the JS change function it will come again into this function, thats why i need the ckecker if statment.

```js
 $("#uploadRiskPolicyFile").change(function () {
        var checker = $("input[name='FileUploadPolicy']").val();
        if (checker != '') {
            if (confirm("Willst du das File hochladen?")) {
                var riskId = $(managementRiskPdfMenu).data("riskId");
                var control = document.getElementById("uploadRiskPolicyFile");
                var files = control.files[0];

                var success = UploadRiskPdf(riskId, 1, files);
                if (success) {
                    LoadManagementPdfMenu(riskId);
                    $("input[name='FileUploadPolicy']").val('');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: after submit via ajax are you able to save it to server if files having same name?